# attributeError: can't set attribute with flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy version 2.1 which installs sqlalchemy version 1.x.

My below code which first fetch an array of resultset and then loop over to modify an existing attribute used to work but now it does not.

```
question_topic = Question.query.join(Topic).join(User,User.id==Question.user_id).add_columns(User.email,Question.question, Question.date, Topic.topic_name, Question.id, Topic.question_id)\
        .filter(Question.id == Topic.question_id).all()



for q_t in question_topic:
    q_t.topic_name = q_t.topic_name + "some text..."
```

I get following error:
attributeError: can't set attribute with 'topic_name'

Comment: Code works if i downgrade SQLalchemy to 0.9

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/changelog/changelog_10.html

Comment: @hjpotter92 i did go through release notes but unable to locate the exact feature/bug which added this behaviour and how can i restore the old behaviour. Can you please help?

Comment: Your filter expression should be your join for `Topic`.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/changelog/changelog_10.html#change-8dff32ea855329842148a57ea75d4663

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error ("AttributeError: can't set attribute" error) on a new column. It was due to a @property that I had previously added and that had the same name than the column.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same error, i try to modify an sqlalchemy object that get from my db.
When i print it i see a tuple, check if it is not. 
I solve the problem by refactoring my model, i want to add some field on my relation. 
First i have :

```
assoc_host_software = Table("host_software", Base.metadata,
    Column("host_id", Integer, ForeignKey("host.id")),
    Column("software_id", Integer, ForeignKey("software.id")),
)
```

then i try

```
assoc_host_software = Table("host_software", Base.metadata,
    Column("host_id", Integer, ForeignKey("host.id")),
    Column("software_id", Integer, ForeignKey("software.id")),
    Column("in_date",DateTime, unique=False, nullable=True),
    Column("out_date",DateTime, unique=False, nullable=True)
)
```

when i get the object from assoc_host_software and try to update him i get the same error as you get.
I understand (and remember) that is not the right way to modify an object from relation many to many
so 
i convert my model to

```
class Host_Software(Base):
    """Model for relation host software."""
    __tablename__ = 'host_software'
    host_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("host.id"), primary_key=True)
    software_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("software.id"), primary_key=True)
    in_date = Column(DateTime, unique=False, nullable=True)
    out_date = Column(DateTime, unique=False, nullable=False)
    software = relationship("Software", backref="software_associations")
    host = relationship("Host", backref="host_associations")
```

i hope that will help