# Dynamically search and modify value in table via SQLAlchemy (error setattr can't set attribute )

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to python , SQLAlchemy and stackfoverflow (so sorry if my question is not clear), trying my best.
My question is : How can i update dynamically a value in a database, 
via dynamic filter. I want to remain agnostic from columns name .I want the user to pass a filter to locate a row and the expression of what field to change. The idea is to create an generic function that does that. I am having a problem understanding how to use set attribute for this or maybe there is another way? Thank you

**The imports:**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    mapper,
    relationship,
    sessionmaker)
from sqlalchemy import *
```

**DB initiation and connection**

```
initation = 'mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/km'

kmdb = create_engine( initation, pool_recycle=3600 )  # connect to server
kmdb.echo = False
Conn = kmdb.connect()
Meta = MetaData(bind=kmdb)


My_Session = sessionmaker()
My_Session.configure( bind=kmdb )
MySession=My_Session()
```

**The table description:**

```
country_hdl = Table( 'km_test_mapping', Meta,
                     Column( 'country_mapping_id', Integer, primary_key=True ),
                     Column( 'origin_client_id', String( 40 ) ),
                     Column( 'origin_source_id', String( 30 ) ),
                     Column( 'origin_cntrp_country', String( 30 ) ),
                     Column( 'som_cntrp_country', String( 30 ) ),
                     Column( 'can_use', Boolean ),
                     UniqueConstraint( 'origin_client_id', 'origin_source_id', 'origin_cntrp_country' )
                     )
```

**# mapped table to class Country**

```
class Country( object ):
    pass
mapper( Country, country_hdl )
cntry = Country()
```

**#The dynamic variables to pass(filter and value to change):**

```
#I want to dynamically search for origin_client_id = MX01 and if found replace origin_client_id with CAL01. These values are passed as variables by user
    myfilter = {'origin_source_id': 'MX01’} 
    updatefieldvalue={'origin_client_id':'CAL01’}
```

**#The  query function:**

```
query = MySession.query( country_hdl ).filter_by( **myfilter ) 
results = query.all()
```

**#Replacing the field(s) if found:**

```
if results:  
  for column,value in updatefieldvalue.items():  
    setattr(results[0],column,value)
```

**The error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/gerardrafie/Developments/KPIMinds/sampleapp/db.py", 
line 63, in <module> . 
setattr(results[0],column,value) .  
AttributeError: can't set attribute .
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519428/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute-with-flask-sqlalchemy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391039/cant-set-attribute-on-result-objects-in-sqlalchemy-flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By querying on the table name, you're querying on a static result set that cannot be changed.
However, if you query on the mapped class (`session.query(Country)`, then you will be able to change the resulting objects.